How can I maintain a modified version of a Python library and ensure that my application installs this version automatically using requirements.txt?
I want to avoid manually editing the library code each time I install dependencies and is there a way to get future updates to the library while still preserving my changes?
I am currently clueless on how can I achieve this.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Fork the library > make your changes on your fork > add the fork's repository URL to your requirements.txt.
requirements.txt:
git+https://github.com/<your_username>/<forked-library-repo>.git@<your-branch>#egg=<original_library_name>

replace everything with a <>

To get future updates to the library while still preserving your chages. You will probably need to add the original repository as a remote in your local clone > fetch and merge changes from the original repository > resolve merge conflicts manualy > push the updated code to your fork.

take these steps with a grain of salt... I have not testes this but in theory this should work.

